# Not able to open an URL in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to open a different domain url in iframe which requires bearer token to be passed in header. I am getting a cross origin error.

```html
<iframe id="output-frame-id" width='100%' height='100%' src="https://punlinvdi158:8089/servicesNS/nobody/tripwire-connect/data/ui/views/vulnerability_inventory_details" />
```

Comment: "I am getting a cross origin error" — And what **exactly** does that error message say?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options

Comment: Refused to display 'https://punlinvdi158:8089/servicesNS/nobody' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.  This is a different domain